# Newton iteration for a linear operator

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

For a nonlinear operator $\mathcal{N}$, $\mathcal{N}(u)=0$ can be solved through Newton iteration, where many steps is usually needed.

If the operator is linear, and we still use the Netwen iteration to solve. Can we solve $\mathcal{L}(u)=0$ in a single step?

For example, if the exact solution is $\bar{u}$, and the initial guess is $\hat{u}$, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\hat{u})}{\partial u} \Delta u = -\mathcal{L}(\hat{u})$, and $\hat{u}+\Delta u = \bar{u}$?

For a scaler problem it is quite trivial, but I'm not sure this result can be generalized to  all the linear operaor, i.e. multi-dimensional, $\mathcal{L}(u)=\mathcal{L}(u,u')$ etc.

Comment: As $L[u+sv]=L[u]+sL[v]$ for linear operators, the ability to solve the linear equation for $Δu$ translates directly into the ability to solve for $u$. There is really no advantage in this abstract setting. One could refer to multigrid methods or similar where a sequence of successively improved solution approximations occurs naturally.

Comment: Hi @Lutz Lehmann, I agree there could be a better way to solve it. However, as we have already developed a code to solve the nonlinear operator, and we'd like to solve the linear operator with minimun modification, I was wondering if we can solve it in a single Newton iteration step?